# How do I add events to a calendar with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, calendar, createelement

I am making a calendar with vanilla JavaScript. I would like to be able to enter events into a specific day and be able to see that day's events when I click on the day. I'm trying to do this inside the for loop that creates the calendar days but I feel like there is a better way I haven't come up with. Right now I can enter events but they do not show up for the specified day only. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Basically what I am asking is how do I create a separate list container for each calendar day that will display the events when I click on it after they have been entered.

```
for (i = 1; i <= days; i++) {
    let calendarDay = document.createElement('div')
    calendarDay.id = Math.random(1, 1000);
    calendarDay.className = 'calendar-day';
    calendarDay.innerHTML = i;
    dateContainer.appendChild(calendarDay);

    
    calendarDay.addEventListener('click', () => {
        
    newEvent.style.display = 'block';
    eventList.addEventListener('submit', (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.className = 'task-list';
        li.innerHTML = task.value;
        // calArray.push(task.value)
        // li.innerHTML = calArray;
        newEvent.appendChild(li);
        task.value = '';
  
    });
    });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a click event on the whole calendar, not every day. Also, when you create item-days, you need to give each a unique identifier. When you click on the calendar, handle the click on the specific day. Inside the handler you create a block element to output events related to the selected day. You take the data from the repository by its unique identifier and render it.

For example like this:

```
calendar.addEventListener("click", event => {
    if (event.target.className == "calendarday") {
        let data = eventsStore.getData(event.target.id); // events data
        // create elements and data render
    }
});
```

Comment: Great! This is helpful. Thank you! I did not think of putting a click event on the whole calendar. I also wasn't sure if I needed to give each day an id or not.